# Is the number of year plus s used as an adj?

Tags: adjectives

For a sentence from a ACT English test:

> Her goal was to revive the literary boom of the 1920s Harlem Renaissance of which she had been a part.

So my question is, since there is no comma after "1920s", does that mean it functions as an adjective?

Comment: How can 1920's possibly be an adjective? It's a noun phrase functioning as a genitive determiner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, like "Harlem" in that sentence, a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). As is generally the case, it can be rewritten with "of": "Harlem Renaissance of the 1920s."

Comment: Could you expand beyond this, like when a noun function as a noun adjunct? I mean, it is not like all nouns can be used this way?

Comment: I'd say that it's a noun phrase functioning as a genitive determiner in the nominal "1920's Harlem Renaissance".